Fragmentos Thymeleaf dentro de outro fragmento thymeleaf
Seria possível inserir um fragmento thymeleaf dentro de outro fragmento?
<html th:fragment="lateral" data-bs-theme="auto">
   <div class="container">  
       <div th:fragment="interno"/>
   </div>
</html>

como seria a passagem dessas informações? Para substituir meu codigo HTML no fragmento 'lateral', seria assim:
<div th:replace="~{fragments/minhalateral.html :: lateral}"></div>

Mas como seria a inclusão do código HTML para o fragmento 'interno'?
